# Are there any programs which can read xcdatamodel(d) files?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I seem to remember, perhaps wrongly, being able to open Xcode Core Data model files in OmniGraffle. Please note, I'm talking model definitions, NOT data stores.

What I want is to be able to output a user-friendly description of the Core Data model for non-developers (managers, clients) who don't have Xcode. OmniOutliner would be ideal, because then I could generate a PDF or an HTML file.

I do know about mogenerator. I could write templates and then merge the output, but that's rather more effort than it's worth at the moment. Maybe later.